# Showing triangle inequality for a norm

Tags: analysis, normed-spaces

I want to determine whether the following is a norm or not:
\begin{equation}                                                                                                                                                            
\max\{|x_1-x_2|, |x_1+x_2|, |x_3|, |x_4|, \ldots,|x_n|\}                                                                                                                      
\end{equation}
Specifically, I want to know whether the triangle inequality holds:
\begin{equation}                                                                                                                                                            
||x+y|| \leq ||x||+||y||                                                                                                                                                    
\end{equation} I also noted that this is very similar to the $L-\infty$ norm:
\begin{equation}                                                                                                                                                            
||x||_\infty = \max_{1\leq i\leq n}|x_i|                                                                                                                                    
\end{equation}
Since this norm is identical to the $L-\infty$ norm except for the first two elements, it suffices to consider the cases when $|x_1+x_2|$ and $|x_1-x_2|$ are the maximum
elements.
I am stuck on this thought, not being able to cover all the cases. (I have been thinking what if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are large but $y_1$ and $y_2$ are small. Anyway, this
leads me to believe that there is a simpler way.

1. How do I determine whether the triangle inequality holds?
2. What is a good strategy in general when dealing with maxima?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the map $f:(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots,x_n)\mapsto(x_1-x_2,x_1+x_2,x_3,\ldots,x_n)$. It is easy to show that this is linear and invertible. So, you have got a linear bijection on your hands, and your candidate norm is $|x| = |f(x)|_\infty$.

Then the problem reduces to "given a linear bijection $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ and a known norm $|\cdot|$, show that $|f(\cdot)|$ is also a norm" which (I think) is true and much easier to tackle.

Comment: Is the following usage of the fundamental theorem of linear algebra sufficient: $\dim(V) = \dim(n(f)) + \dim(f(x))$. $\dim(V) = \dim(f(x)) = n$. Thus $\dim(n(f))=0 \implies$ invertibility.

Comment: If you mean the null space of $f$ by $n(f)$, this is exactly correct. Though I think your notation is nonstandard.

Comment: $||f(x+y)|| = ||f(x)+f(x)|| \leq ||f(x)||+||f(y)||$. The last step is due to the fact that $f$ is bijective (but I don't see it too clearly). I was thinking intuitively if $f: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ then since $||\cdot||$ is a norm and $f(x),f(y)\in\mathbb{R}$ then it must satisfy the triangle inequality. Could you give a better explanation?